# Is microcode and machine code the same thing?

Tags: assembly, controller, avr, machine-code

I had my first class of micro code few days back and noticed that some syntax of micro coding Atmel AVR microcontroller is quite similar to that of Assembly Level Language.
However there are some syntax which do not match for common instructions. So are they the same?

For what I know, Assembly Level Language is just a programming language where the compiler translates that to machine language. Where is microcode coming in here?

Also what does the following sentence mean?
"The assembler instruction ADD R1,R0 corresponds to the binary instruction word in Hexadecimal:
OC(for Add) 01 (0001 for register 1 and 0000 for register 0)"

I know that the data/operands in the registers are in hexadecimal during ADD instruction but what is that 0C01?

Comment: The Wikipedia article's introduction seems like it answers this fairly clearly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode

Comment: and what is that 0c?

Comment: `0c` happens to be the code for `add`. It's just an assigned opcode number.

Comment: Microcode is the implementation of machine code. It's basically "set in stone" by the manufacturer of the CPU and the end user cannot program in it, even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are  not the same thing.

> noticed that some syntax of micro coding Atmel AVR microcontroller is quite similar to that of Assembly Level Language.

You are not writing microcode for an AVR - you will be writing assembly.

> For what I know, Assembly Level Language is just a programming language where the compiler translates that to machine language. Where is microcode coming in here?

Microcode is not coming into play here. Assembly is indeed, a language (though a machine-specific language) that implements that machines `instruction set`. However, your statement oversimplifies it somewhat - you have described **part** of a typical build process.

More commonly, you will be programming an AVR using C (likely the avr-gcc toolchain).

A C program is compiled (which in turn takes several steps; pre-processing, linking etc) **into** assembly (if you're building a solution in Microchip Studio, look at the .lss output file, this is your generated assembly).

This assembly is then further processed into machine code (the .hex output file in Microchip Studio).

Therefore, the same C will result in different assembly during the build process, when the target machine changes. I.e. whether you're building for an AVR, PIC, STM, SAM etc, as will the machine code.

However, small/simple microcontrollers typically do not implement microcode.

Microcode is more commonly 'used'/implemented on much more complex/powerful CPUs. To understand this, you must first be confident you understand what an `instruction set` is, if not - I suggest doing some digging there.

On complex CPUs, microcode is a layer of software which **emulates** a given instruction set, using often simpler underlying hardware. I.e., allows a machine whose hardware does not directly implement a given instruction, to support that instruction by using it's own instruction set to implement that of another.

For example, a CPU without hardware divide instruction (let's call this instruction DIV for now...), could 'pretend' to support a DIV, by executing a series of instructions that it's own hardware really can execute, to **emulate** the behaviour of a DIV, i.e. lots of adds, shifts, rotates, carries etc.

However, on an AVR - your instruction set is fixed, it is what it is, and it isn't what it isn't. For example, a divide on AVR is performed by the compiler generating the appropriate instructions, as there is no divide instruction, nor any microcode on the device that will perform a divide, using it's underlying native instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Microcode can be machine code, or can be thought of it but in general we say no it is not the same.   There is concept and there is implementation.  The Wikipedia link in the comments is as mentioned in the comment, the answer here.  Typically candidates for microcoding are CISC architectures and RISC are intentionally not as part of the whole concept.  Some may have the term microarchitecture used but that is not microcoding, think state machine.

In some CISC there is an expectation that you can for example add register X with memory location y and store the result in memory location Z.  That is a lot of separate steps.  The memory transactions on top of the simple add.  With a RISC or let's say load store architecture, your ALU type operations ADD, SUB, XOR, etc are done only with registers and the result can only land in a register (or flags).  So to perform the above you need three instructions read from Y into some register, add X and that register saving to some register then store that last register into location Z.  This is the same thing that microcode might do depending on the microcoding.  But as the Wikipedia article describes that may be broken down further, set the mux to connect register X to operand A of the alu.  Set the address bus to Y, set the mux to select data bus to alu B, etc...plus the bus control and timing to get the read and write to work.

Understand that there is no reason to assume that the same microcode architecture is used for the same family every time.  In particular assume that x86 for example has had different underlying architectures from the beginning to now, at one point there were two separate x86 teams that would leapfrog each other and you could see that in the optimization and performance, but was also a problem because code tuned for one would be slow on the next but okay on the one after that.   Microcode or not, obviously, you can implement the same instruction set architecture with completely different logic.  Take 100 engineers and give them the avr instruction set documentation and you will get somewhere between 1 and 100 different implementations that will all execute the same binary.  (closer to if not 100).  Same goes for processors that evolve like x86 and mips and such, the implementation changes over time for various reasons.

There have been implementations that used a known stand-alone processor/architecture to microcode another architecture (x86).  To be fair that usually means bitslice/VLIW and not just some other risc or cisc.

If you look at the visual6502 stuff, folks have begun (well this started many years ago now) to slice and photograph older chips and then reverse engineer them.  But independent of that think about the technology when the 6502 and other processors of that generation.  The mask set was done literally by hand by a human on a drafting table.  Done in large scale then shrunk down.  I assume about the cost, but the risk was much higher than today to make a successful chip, it was all humans doing logic by hand and then implementing the gates and traces by hand.   So instead of coming up with risc and all the logic required to implement everything, you created muxes and buses, you had rigid bus cycles (put the address out, chip select, and read/write and then four cycles later the answer must be there)(which matched with memory tech of the time) an actual alu, etc.  your microcode was, and you can see this in the 6502 in particular, a rom that was programmed later.  Very wise design.  All you have to do is get these primitive buses and muxes right in the actual logic then you implement microcode such that for example the opcode byte (and it makes sense why the architectures of the time used an actual opcode as a byte or less) was the address into the rom maybe there were 8 rom locations or 16 for example for each instruction.  If there is a bug in the logic of a no-microcoded system then you have to respin the chip and start over, very expensive.  But if there a bug in a microcoded processor you at least stand a chance that you can change the microcode in the rom (in the 6502 as an example) and not spin the chip.   It was a very wise and very understandable path that history took.

As our tools have evolved and computing power has evolved we do a TON of work pre-silicon in simulations, emulations.  If you can find what "stepping" a particular processor chip has.  (not always available to us).

```
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
```

You will find that the stepping has gotten lower over time.  That is not really how we do a stepping it is usually a letter then number A0, A1, A2...B0,B1, etc...The step in the number is if you can fix the problem in the metal layers, the layers that connect the transistors.  if you have to mess with the transistor layers then it changes the letter.  used to be that you would be well into the letters before you had a product you could deliver, today you can see A0,A1 products.  Because of the tools.   But this is all part of the evolution of chip technology which includes the very sane solution of microcoding.  It is certainly possible to implement an x86 without microcode, but you will from time to time see a microcode update into the bios or operating system.   And it is certainly possible to microcode a risc, and in some well known university programs with very simple processors, they have an elaborate microengine.  Something you can implement in a few dozen lines of verilog becomes this massive thing, for educational purposes.

When you have ADD R1,R0 that is assembly language, and it generates machine code 0X0C01 is what you indicated.  This is NOT microcode, this is machine code or machine language. And the version that is more human readable ADD R0,R1 is assembly langauge.

In the case of atmel and the AVR I suspect that while one CAN re-implement the design, I assume they just keep taking the same design and maybe add more memory or add more flash or more uarts or build it with a smaller/cheaper process.  That is the expectation with AVR, PIC, msp430 and some others like that.  x86, arm, etc have evolved, their architecture as well as implementation.  arm happens to be flexible enough to be used in an mcu, but also a full on pc or server, so it confuses the concept here.

If you look at 6502, z80, x86, avr, etc, these 8 bit instruction machines, the opcode just a code, sometimes if you look at the map there might be a pattern, but I suspect it was just the human keeping track of all the combinations and not any kind of decoding.  Where ARM, MIPS, RISC-V, etc, the "instruction" has opcodes if you will but they can vary in size, mips, riscv which is heavily influenced by mips will have a fixed opcode area, limiting how many bits are left in the fixed size instruction, and then for some opcodes there is additional opcode fields.  ARM took a different approach allow for some instructions to maximize the use of the instruction bits and have larger immediates, or more operands and then other instructions more detail in the opcode, so you start with the msbit and divide the pool of instructions in half or top two bits and quarters, and that is how they describe the instruction decoding in their documentation.  It looks difficult to the average programmer that learned about opcodes and maybe wrote some x86 code, but it makes a lot of sense from an efficient use of the instruction and not any harder to implement.

So the 0x0C opcode for that instruction is just an opcode, you look it up in the documentation.  The additional bytes may be decoded or they may also be just a code that you look up in a table.  You can see this well in x86 where the first byte is just an opcode/instruction, then the following bytes may be more cryptic byte patters or they may start to be decoded directly where some bits indicate a specific register, etc...And this is all still machine code.  It is very rare if even possible to "see" what the microcode looks like for a given processor (think x86), you would likely need to work there and then climb the latter to a position where you have a need and can be trusted with the sources to the core.  With purchased IP like ARM and mips and such, you get the code, you can see it. You just can't talk about it nor share it. Although in some cases it can be distributed in a way that is obfuscated so that you cannot understand it.

---

In your class you are learning assembly language which then is assembled into machine code.  You do not have a microengine in the atmel avr chips.  There is no microcode here.  The machine code bits are defined by an instruction set architecture (ISA), AVR is an instruction set architecture.  The atmel/microchip chips are an implementation of that ISA.  They can be fed those bits and will execute them per the architecture.

Assembly language ADD R0,R1 is a human readable programming language that uses an assembler, a tool, to convert the assembly language into machine language/code.  This means that you can have different assembly languages that generate the same machine code, assembly language is a programming language.

In the case of AVR it is like x86 it is not just an architecture but complete chips with other logic.  AVR from atmel now microchip will have a set of tools that you can acquire, some folks charge some give for free, for mcu vendors it is best to give it away for free.  In any case there is usually an assembly language defined by the processor vendor that goes with the documentation that includes the assembly language and the machine code definition, the opcodes, etc.  The expectation is that the assembly language shown in that documentation matches the tool created or commissioned by the processor vendor.  Other tools for that architecture may not conform to the processor documentation but are still fully capable of generating working machine code.  (for ARM, MIPS, RISC-V, etc the processor vendor has the documentation and tools, and then some chip vendor buys that IP (like st, nxp, ti, etc for arm) and puts it in their chip with IP from sources other than arm and the chip vendors glue to hold it all together.  But the IP vendor in that case has a document and an associated assembly language and machine code, generally.